# not able to debug this code related to central limit theorem

Tags: python, debugging, math, statistics

I had this problem where a maximum load of 9800 poundss could be carried in a lift. there was a cargo of boxes with average weight 205 pounds and standard deviation of 15 pounds. i had to find the probability of 49 boxes being carried by the lift.

code:

```
import math
maxwt=int(input())
n=int(input())
mean=int(input())
var=int(input())

var_sum=math.sqrt(n)*var
meansum=mean*n

def cdf(x,mean,var):
    z=x-mean/var
    return  (1+math.erf(z/(math.sqrt(2))))/2

print(round(cdf(maxwt,meansum,var_sum),4))
```

Input:

```
9800
49
205
15
```

Expected Output:

```
0.0098
```

My output:

```
1.0
```

Here is another code i took from somewhere else and it returns correct output although i am unable to see any difference in this or my code

```
import math

x = int(input())
n = int(input())
mu = int(input())
sigma = int(input())

mu_sum = n * mu 
sigma_sum = math.sqrt(n) * sigma

def cdf(x, mu, sigma):
    Z = (x - mu)/sigma
    return 0.5*(1 + math.erf(Z/(math.sqrt(2))))

print(round(cdf(x, mu_sum, sigma_sum), 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct equation is:

```
z = (x-mean)/var
```

You have forgotten the brackets.

Comment: thank you. actually had figured it out later while solving another similar question that i made such a silly mistake.

Comment: Great! Could you just pick an answer and mark this thread as answered? It will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
z=x-mean/var
```

while the other has

```
Z = (x - mu)/sigma
```